# Best way to get the downloadUrl of thumbnail generated by Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
      StorageReference newfilepath = mStorage.child("User Submission Images").child(user_id).child("photo1g.jpg");
      newfilepath.putFile(photo1ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
              final Uri dwnldUri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
              businessDBRef.child(user_id).child("photos1").setValue(dwnldUri.toString());

              StorageReference thumbpath = mStorage.child("User Submission Images").child(user_id);
              thumbpath.child("thumb_photo1v.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                      businessDBRef.child(user_id).child("thumb1").setValue(uri.toString());
                  }
              });

              mProgess.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
```

After the image gets uploaded i try to pass the download url of the thumbnail into the database but i assume that my code executes faster than the creation of the thumbnail so i get this

> StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                           Object does not exist at location.

When checking the Firebase storage the thumbnail is there with the download url accessible. Is there any workaround for this? maybe a way to wait for the thumbnail to generate first and then get the download URl??

Comment: i think you actually not getting a thumbnail ,its the download uri of file itself so when you get this this give you a file not thumbnail of file..as permy knowledge

Comment: I don't see here where you're using Cloud Functions for Firebase.  This is only client code for Android.

Comment: @Uttam Meerwal According to the Firebase docs Storageref.getDownloadUrl() will give me the download url of the file and using setValue()  i move that url to My Firebase database so that i can retrieve using Picasso

Comment: @Doug Stevenson You're right the code i attached is the client side but i do use cloud function to automatically generate thumbnail of any image i upload in Firebase Storage.

Comment: @DyceKim yes you said it rightbut piccasso can show the thumbnail you can't save that thumbnail or upload it.you add downloadurl to database you doing it good it your way but as per the question there is no way to store thumbnail or get its url

Comment: @DyceKim i suggest you to go to documentation of firebase storage and read about using metadata of firebase storage maybe it will help

Comment: @Uttam I suggest  you take a look at this, thanks for trying to help though. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm using https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail to generate my thumbnails so my problem is that when calling thumbpath.child("thumb_photo1v.jpg").getDownloadUrl() the thumbnail hasnt been generated yet

Comment: Obviously the thumbnail doesn't get generated instantly.  You'll have to figure out a way to get the function to notify your app that the thumbnail is complete before it can try to download it.  Maybe write something to the database and have the client listen for the update.

Comment: Thanks man, I think i might have an idea.